# MacBook Pro failing Internet Recovery with exclamation mark

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, charging, recovery

My MacBook Pro from 2009 restarts itself and doesn't charge, I tried recovery hd but I hadn't used Time Machine so the option is not there and now I'm trying Internet Recovery it give an exclamation mark on the big round web icon.

Answer (score 1):

That Mac is too old to use Internet Recovery.
[Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-lb/HT202313)

Your choices are …

- the Recovery Partition
- a boot DVD
- a USB key, made on another machine
- [Hardware test](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT201257)

Answer (score 0):

Try retting the System Management Controller [SMC] (instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)). This may be because some settings may be messed up.

There may also be a short circuit in your charger which may be causing your MacBook Pro to crash since it is the only way to protect its self (this is just a guess)

If this doesn't work please let me know and I will try and find another solution.

**Edit**

It may also be the circuit in your MacBook Pro.